# Create an entry with RichText data via contentful management php sdk

Tags: php, rtf, richtext, contentful, contentful-management

I have searched extensively for an answer to this, contacted contentful support (and being ignored) and tried every permutation I can possible think of. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to create a new entry via the contentful management sdk with RichText content.

**The setter:**

```
$entry->setField('rtf', 'en-GB', file_get_contents('content-blocks/rtf/zzz.rtf'));
```

**The contents of that file are:**

```
{
  "nodeType": "document",
  "data": {},
  "content": [
    {
      "nodeType": "paragraph",
      "content": [
        {
          "nodeType": "text",
          "value": "Test text",
          "marks": [],
          "data": {}
        }
      ],
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also tried directly inputting the contents, stripping whitespace etc. This json block is also generated from contentfuls own markdown to richtext converter.

**The response:**

```
{\n
  "sys": {\n
    "type": "Error",\n
    "id": "InvalidEntry"\n
  },\n
  "message": "Validation error",\n
  "details": {\n
    "errors": [\n
      {\n
        "name": "type",\n
        "value": "{\n  \"nodeType\": \"document\",\n  \"data\": {},\n  \"content\": [\n    {\n      \"nodeType\": \"paragraph\",\n      \"content\": [\n        {\n          \"nodeType\": \"text\",\n          \"value\": \"Test text\",\n          \"marks\": [],\n          \"data\": {}\n        }\n      ],\n      \"data\": {}\n    }\n  ]\n}\n",\n
        "type": "RichText",\n
        "details": "The type of \"value\" is incorrect, expected type: RichText",\n
        "path": [\n
          "fields",\n
          "rtf",\n
          "en-US"\n
        ]\n
      }\n
    ]\n
  },\n
  "requestId": "a603e57d716b7af9c5c8078f2701fc41"\n
}\n
```

The docs for this scenario are non-existent so any help you can give would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but if anyone stumbles upon it there is a closed Github Issue that contains the answer.

[HTML String to RichText via PHP SDK #160](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-management.php/issues/160)

And an Example with a more simplified structure:

```
$bodyValue = [
        'data' => [],
        'content' => [
            [
                'nodeType' => 'paragraph',
                'content' => [
                    [
                        'nodeType' => 'text',
                        'data' => [],
                        'value' => 'Hello, is it me you\'re looking for?',
                        'marks' => [
                            ['type' => 'code'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'data' => [],
            ],
        ],
        'nodeType' => 'document',
    ];

    $entry->setField('rtf', 'en-GB', $bodyValue);
```